# Why this if loop not working?(BGI shapes)

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to creates shapes, make them bounce of edges but my if loop doesn't seem to working and I don't know why.
This line moves the shape:

```
line1.x  += line1.xvelocity;
line1.y  += line1.yvelocity;
line1.x2 += line1.xvelocity;
line1.y2 += line1.yvelocity;
```

I want to keep the shape in 640x480 so i wrote

```
if (line1.x >> 640) line1.xvelocity *= (-1);
if (line1.x << 0) line1.xvelocity *= (-1);
if (line1.y >> 480) line1.yvelocity *= (-1);
if (line1.y << 0) line1.yvelocity *= (-1);
if (line1.x2 >> 640) line1.xvelocity *= (-1);
if (line1.x2 << 0) line1.xvelocity *= (-1);
if (line1.y2 >> 480) line1.yvelocity *= (-1);
if (line1.y2 << 0) line1.yvelocity *= (-1);
```

I tried using `||`, or just using `x,y` or `x2,y2` coordinates.
Any help?
Thank you.

```
class Line: public GenericShape
{
public:
    int x2, y2;
    Line();
    Line(int x_in, int y_in, int color_in, int xvel, int yvel, int x2_in, int y2_in)
        : GenericShape(x_in, y_in, color_in, xvel, yvel),
          x2(x2_in),
          y2(y2_in)
    {}
    void draw() const;
};

Line line1(50, 150, 4, 2, -3, 180, 60); // xvelocity=2 yvelocity =-3
```

Comment: Do some debugging then come back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in

```
if (line1.x >> 640)
```

is always zero, because the '>>' is a bitwise Shift-Right operation, not the comparison. It is equivalent to the division of line1.x by 2^640.

Change it to

```
if(line1.x >= 640)
```

In the other conditions change '<<' to '<' and '>>' to '>=' also.